# Does session_start() clear cookies data?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-cookie

I built a tree menu with treeview , having the option `persist` set to cookie. When I click a submenu of a particular menu then I call an `ajax` to retrieve database data and rewrite accordingly the code of the HTML `unordered list` of the tree menu, then I rebuild the menu by calling `treeview`.

In that ajax I call `session_start()` at the beginning. My question is : does `session_start()` clear any previously set cookie ?

Comment: Why don't you try it? All you need is a browser...

Comment: session_start basically generates a unique id and set a cookie in client or pass via URL ,and doesn't delete your other cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It might add another cookie as a session cookie, and if that cookies name conflicts with any previously set cookie, that cookie might get deleted or overwritten or become unaccessible to PHP, but this is not the regular case.

Answer (score 0):

session_start allow you to manage sessions:

1- take control over an existing session

2- create new session

- manipulate some header directive

Answer (score -1):

Unless your first cookie is set using the `$_SESSION` variable then they shouldn't affect each other. Regular cookies and PHP sessions are independent.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mix things up a bit. Regular cookies DO affect the session cookie and vice versa. They are not independent.